# How Microsoft Hides C# Internal Classes from a DLL's Metadata?

Tags: c#, reflection, reverse-engineering, cil, ilspy

It all started when I wanted to analyze the code around CVE-2017-8759. I knew that the fix for the CVE was in a class named WsdlParser.cs inside System.Runtime.Remoting.dll which is part of the .Net Framework. You probably have this dll on your computer at a location similar to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.7\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll

I used ilspycmd to re-assemble the code back to C#, and noticed that the WsdlParser.cs was missing in the output directory:

[image]

I later used CFF Explorer and saw that this type is indeed missing in the metadata in TypeDefs:

[image]

However, I know for a fact that this class is there:

- It's in Microsoft's documentation: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Runtime.Remoting/metadata/wsdlparser.cs.html
- When using reflection and LoadAssembly() I was able to find the class:

  ```
      Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll");

      foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
      {
          if (!type.FullName.EndsWith("WsdlParser"))
          {
              continue;
          }

          Console.WriteLine("Great Success");
      }
  ```

I noticed that this behavior is consistent to all internal classes in this dll, but I don't understand how it makes sense. My guess is there might be a post-build procedure to remove data of internal types, but if so, how was I able to find the class by loading the assembly? I thought that the CIL loads types using the TypeDef metadata, but is there an additional space where this data is stored?

In order to understand it better, I created a C# test project with an internal class, and inspected the metadata using CFF Explorer. The internal class was there, as it should be, in debug and in release builds.

So what is this voodoo?

Thanks guys.

Comment: The Explorer is using the headers of the data types to find object.  I don't think it is checking the executable stack for locals object.  And if an object was not constructed you also won't find the object (when null).

Comment: Have a look at the `Assembly` property of that loaded type. Its not the assembly you think you have loaded. Its actually from the GAC. (For me `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Remoting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Remoting.dll`) If you take that real file and throw it into a disassembler you will find the `WsdlParser` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've found is a [Reference Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/reference-assemblies). There's a big clue to that in the path you found it in.

> Reference assemblies are a special type of assembly that contain only the minimum amount of metadata required to represent the library's public API surface. They include declarations for all members that are significant when referencing an assembly in build tools, but *exclude all member implementations and declarations of private members that have no observable impact on their API contract.*

(My *emphasis*)

And:

> Generating reference assemblies for your libraries can be useful when your library consumers need to build their programs against many different versions of the library. Distributing implementation assemblies for all these versions might be impractical because of their large size. Reference assemblies are smaller in size, and distributing them as a part of your library's SDK reduces download size and saves disk space.

No magic, just a publicly documented means of distributing smaller files when the full file isn't required.

These assemblies are used at *compile time*, but not at *runtime*. For that you need an implementation assembly, which will be supplied by other means, such as it having been placed in the GAC.